# Extracting text from a text file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep, regular-expression, string

I have a large text file that is all one line.  In the text are several sections that looks like `foo=12345` and I need to extract them all as separate lines, ignoring the rest of the file.

For example:

```
random junk foo=12345 more junk random junk foo=2345 junk foo=7654 junk random foo=5432 junk
```

What I want to get out is:

```
12345
2345
7654
5432
```

I know how to write the regex to extract the `foo=([0-9]+)`, but I'm not sure how to apply that to the text and get the lines out in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$> echo "random junk foo=12345 more junk random junk foo=2345 junk foo=7654 junk random foo=5432 junk" | grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "(?<=foo=)[0-9]+"
12345
2345
7654
5432
```

What we've done here is use lookbehind regex in `"(?<=foo=)[0-9]+"`.

Comment: Note that the `--perl-regexp` option is available to GNU versions of `grep`.  Non-Linux systems may not default to the GNU version.

Comment: According to the perlre man page, you can also write this regex as `foo=\K[0-9]+`, which may be "significantly more efficient".

Comment: Great! This works perfectly.  I'm on OS X, btw.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `awk` to parse the long line into records.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";RS=" "}/^foo=/{print $2}'
```

This sets each "word" as a separate record, and within that word, to separate fields with '='.  Then just output the right side of the '=' when the left side is "foo".  Need to use the regexp instead of `$1=="foo"` since if there is no '=', the first field is the same as the entire record.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with shell constructs alone: read the data into a variable, then split this variable at the characters in `$IFS` (whitespace by default) and retain the chunks that you want. A variable substitution outside double quotes undergoes word splitting (which we want here) and filename generation (a.k.a. globbing, which we don't want), so turn off globbing with `set +f` first.

```
set +f
for x in $(cat /path/to/file); do
  case "$x" in
    foo=*) echo "${x#*=}";;
  esac
done
set -f
```

Instead of calling `cat`, you can use the `read` builtin.

```
set +f
read -r line </path/to/file
for x in $line; do …
```